# What word can I use for a person/researcher/field who likes to put words in people's mouth?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

For example, someone W (say, historic, like from the 1500's) holds position X because of claim Y (I hate ... because of ...).

What would you call someone A who puts "words in their mouth" (He didn't *mean* Y, he really meant Z). The issue is that X probably didn't mean Z because Z is an anachronistic/out-of-character for W, while Y actually fits W's weltanschauung. (And, say I'm an expert in this field and A is not at all, so I'm qualified to call him out). What should I say? A is a ...?

Comment: if this is an actual situation where you are in disagreement with someone in a work setting, why would you 'call out' rather than ask their reason for their assumption of W's meaning? Otherwise you might say 'A is creating a straw man'. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man

Comment: Does A actually believe in the position he’s taking? Is A aware of the arguments against his position? Or is A knowingly trying to manipulate his listeners?  He might be *ignorant*, misinformed, a manipulator, a radical, or an instigator.*

Answer (score 1):

*A* might be a:
*misinformer*
*misguider*
*misleader*
*misdirector*
*misstater*

All of which say that *A* has not stated the facts are they are. These are not words often used, as, today, *liar* is too commonly used. None of these words state that *A* is being intentionally dishonest, but, rather, mistaken.
If the idea of dishonesty need be applied:

> disingenuous [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/disingenuous)

might describe *A*. Disingenuous is not as strong as *liar*, but is strong enough to offend some people.

> A is being *disingenuous*  about W

is essentially what you describe.

Answer (score 1):

**The Devil can cite Scripture**

The best of sources can be distorted to insert a personal interpretation. Origin: Spoken by Antonio in Shakespeare's *The Merchant of Venice*:

> Mark you this, Bassanio, The devil can cite Scripture for his purpose.

Answer (score 1):

## Quote-miner

Quote mining is another name for the informal fallacy of quoting out of context. it can also be used in non-debate circumstances:

example

> guy 1: This movie isn't funny
>
> cover of movie: guy 1: "funny"
>
> guy 2: man, the quote mining is unbelievable

Quote mining is easily formed into quote miner

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoting_out_of_context

Answer (score 1):

**twist someone's words**:  *A is a twister of words!*

> put words in someone's mouth
>
> English Verb
>
> put words in someone's mouth (third-person singular simple present
>   puts words in someone's mouth, present participle putting words in
>   someone's mouth, simple past and past participle put words in
>   someone's mouth)
>
> ```
> (idiomatic) To say or imply that someone has said something which he or she did not precisely or directly say. quotations ▼
> (idiomatic) To encourage or induce someone to appear to assert something by asking a leading question or by otherwise manipulating
> ```
>
> him or her. quotations ▼
>
> Synonyms
>
> ```
> (say or imply that someone has said a thing which he or she did not precisely or directly say): twist someone's words
> ```
>
> [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_words_in_someone%27s_mouth)