# Idiom for someone who intentionally changes your words in the way he wants?

Tags: expressions

I am looking for an idiom for someone who intentionally changes my words in the the way he wants, however, the point he intentionally says is not what I meant. Somehow, he is changing my words in a bad way to use them against me. Do you know any idiom for this thing that he is doing?

Thank you.

Comment: Related, with the same answers: [What word can I use for a person/researcher in the field who likes to put words in people's mouths?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/378504/what-word-can-i-use-for-a-person-researcher-field-who-likes-to-put-words-in-peop/434892#434892).

Comment: The person *misrepresents* what you said.

Comment: This sounds like an issue for [interpersonal.se].

Answer (score 12):

You could use

> Don't twist my words.

or

Don't distort my words.

***twist someone's words***

> to repeat what someone said in a way that has a different meaning
>
> - He twisted my words and made it seem like I was angry. ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/twist%20someone%27s%20words))

Answer (score 11):

**Put words in/into someone's mouth**

> to suggest that someone said or meant something that he or she did not actually say or mean

*Don't put words in my mouth. I wasn't defending his actions, despite what you may think.*

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: Not quite - bad intent is not automatically implied.

Answer (score 1):

The person is using a [straw man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man). This idiom suggests that rather than engaging with you, a strong opponent, they have replaced you with a straw man, which is easier to knock down.

Comment: This is related, but only applies if the person twisting words is doing so in order to then disagree with the person who originally spoke them, and succeed because the twisted words still support the same position, but do so inadequately. If they are twisting the words to misrepresent the position entirely, so knocking it down doesn't actually refute your original argument, or they don't attempt to argue against your position, it's not a straw man.

Comment: A straw man is simply an inaccurate, extreme version of whatever the person opposes. It doesn't have to be words from another person; a lot of the time it's just an idea or philosophy (look at all the political hitjobs).